# Payment form is not displayed

Tags: stripe-payments

Following stripe doc here:
https://stripe.com/docs/elements

if I use

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display form errors -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
</div>
```

it works, the payment form is loaded, but if I simply add a style like this the payment form is not loaded anymore

```
  <div class="input-group" id="card-element">
    <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe strife is looking for the element with no class. or your style is affecting the visibility of the stripe element. Did you check if the element of strife is in the DOM? Any error on dev console?

Comment: Thanks to put me in the right track @RomnickSusa

Comment: Heheh okay nice it is good that you solved your problem. Enjoy coding!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the class is overwritten by Stripe and styles are already implemented, we just have to modify the css